# How can I convert mmp files (Microsoft Project files) to xmind files?

Tags: ms-project, mindmapping

I have received from a friend some files in mmp format. I don't have Microsoft Project but I use xmind. How can I convert mmp files (Microsoft Project files) to xmind files?

Answer (score 0):

The extension for Microsoft Project is .mpp

The .mmp extension is from The old MindManager (maybe version 5 and below?).
MindManager from version 6 onwards uses the extension .mmap

I'm also having problems opening .mmp Mindmanager files in XMIND.
One way would be to open the .mmp files in MindManager 6 or later, and then save as .mmap.
Then you can open the .mmap files in XMIND.